# transitions on Safari on the iPadOS not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

I have written a simple JavaScript code.

All it does, apply a class of 'hide' to the element to hide it (setting opacity to 0), and remove the class to reveal it (setting the opacity back to 1).

transition set on the element itself via css, duration set to 0.5s.

the code works perfectly well, on all browsers on MacOS, all browsers on iOS (on my iPhone - *including Safari*), **EXCEPT the Safari on the iPad!**

I can see the class being applied and removed in devtools. the element is disappearing and reappearing; just without any transitions.

what makes this even weirder, is that Firefox, Edge, and Chrome perform *perfectly well* with the transitions and the code overall on the very same iPad!

the iPad model I'm testing on is: iPad Pro 12.9" with M1; version 15.5.

anyone familiar with such issue?!

Thank you for your time.

sample code:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');

function loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (!src || typeof src !== 'string') throw new Error('src invalid');
      
      img.onload = () => {
        img.onload = null;
        img.onerror = null;
        resolve(img);
      }
      img.onerror = () => {
        img.onload = null;
        img.onerror = null;
        reject(img);
      }
      
      img.src = src;
    }
    catch(error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}

function fadeElement(element, hide = true) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (hide && element.classList.contains('hide')) return resolve(element);
      if (!hide && !element.classList.contains('hide')) return resolve(element);
      
      if (hide) element.classList.add('hide');
      else element.classList.remove('hide');
      
      element.ontransitionend = () => {
        element.ontransitionend = null;
        resolve(element);
      }
    }
    catch(error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}


async function setImage({src, alt}) {
  try {
    if (!src || typeof src !== 'string') throw new Error('src invalid');
    
    img.alt = alt || '';
    
    await fadeElement(img, true);
    await loadImage(src);
    await fadeElement(img, false);
    
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

setImage({src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654378550791-5360093aaf31?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNzN8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 1"})
        .then(()=> {console.log('image loaded')})
        .catch((error) => {throw error});



const interval = setInterval( () => {
  try {
        const srcs = [
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654581066394-18d9549f760b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyMHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 1"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654561610761-dd76686ad98d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxOXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", /* alt: "image 2" */},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654578870260-4fdae0cc4f6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 3"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654525482694-af1b5e9df569?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzOHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", /* alt: "image 4" */},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654513286952-85d043b0c323?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw2OHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 5"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654485604630-d39cc0bab3e3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3OHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 6"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654525217823-7af9e520050c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 7"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654521957182-f0277b65005a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw5MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 8"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654510916856-7533a3b4c368?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw5OXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 9"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654512378443-f14098061c83?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMDB8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", /* alt: "image 10" */},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654513155873-3bfc341f14ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMDR8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 11"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654511794450-e708aa031c43?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMDN8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 12"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654490762536-afdbb92c5bfb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMzB8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", /* alt: "image 13" */},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654423625360-31dee119c5f6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNDJ8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 14"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654446138056-8996ca1e96a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNDF8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 15"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623333769926-a34d46b5fbdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNDB8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", /* alt: "image 16" */},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654505203976-ada2d3e685f8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNDZ8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 17"},
          {src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654448190693-f59b70e5ee3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNjl8fHxlbnwwfHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60", alt: "image 18"},
        ];

        function randomImage(images) {
          return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
        }

        const newSrc = randomImage(srcs);
        setImage(newSrc)
        .then(()=> {console.log('image loaded')})
        .catch((error) => {throw error});
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
}, 6500);
```

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out opacity;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ofeenee/pen/ZErMapq)

Comment: what is the current version of your ipad os?

Comment: "Safari on the iPadOS is driving me crazy" isn't a good question title. Please update your question according to the guidelines:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you want to specify the iPadOS version you're using.

Comment: Done. I changed the title. Sorry about that. @VadimBelyaev

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I can @Jonathan.

Comment: @Jonathan sample code provided.

Comment: it works perfectly on every browser I tested, except on safari on iPadOS.

Comment: iPadOS version 15.5 @RobinHood

Comment: @ofeenee I think the correct syntax is: transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out. see:[MSN transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition). And I would add: opacity:1 to the img attribute just for completeness.

Comment: nope. I tried switching the syntax to transition-property: opacity; transition-duration: 0.5s; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; and still didn't work on iPadOS Safari. works fine everywhere else. @Jonathan

Comment: animation on the iPadOS Safari is also very weird, especially when animation different properties at the same time. works well on other browsers, but on iPadOS Safari, the animations don't happen in the same order you have them set... I'm surprised I cannot find anyone having similar issues on the web.

Comment: @ofeenee I tested your code via CodePen on my iPad Air 2; Version 15.5 and it works without problems.

Comment: Thank you for testing it for me @Jonathan . It's still not working on my iPad, but if it works on yours, I'm satisfied. Maybe it's something with Safari on my own iPad? but that's good news. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if one of my ideas solves your problem, but you could try it.

Changes: ***+ CSS Vendor Prefixes*** see: [MSN Vendor Prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

Use the **visibility** *attribute* with the **opacity** *attribute*.

```
.custom-class{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s; 
}
.custom-class.hide{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**or**

use the **animation** *attribute* with **keyframes**.
Please keep in mind that using my keyframe you only have an in and no out animation.

```
.custom-class{
     opacity: 0;
}
.custom-class.hide{
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-animation: custom-keyframe-in 0.5s;
             animation: custom-keyframe-in 0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes custom-keyframe-in {
     0%{
         opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes custom-keyframe-in {
     0%{
         opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
```